# Does pointer int*x mean x is the integer or x is the hexadecimal address?

Tags: pointers

If you create a pointer int*x, which points to an integer, does that mean the variable of the integer is x? So x is equal to an integer or a hexadecimal address?

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a variable holding the address of an integer.  It is not decimal or hexadecimal.  Those are just terms referring to how a value is displayed.  The value in the variable doesn't change any more than the symbols 12 or 0x0C or XII change the value of twelve.